# Fetching records between two date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want to select all the records in a month.
for eg:
in datebase the records are
Date

1. 01/08/2014
2. 02/08/2014
3. 03/08/2014
4. 04/08/2014
5. 05/08/2014
6. 14/08/2014
7. 05/09/2014
8. 16/09/2014

On that I want to select only for the 01/08/2014 to 14/08/2014.
I write the query as

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT t1.qty, t2.lastname, t2.firstname, t2.date, t3.name,      t2.reservation_id, t2.payable FROM prodinventory AS t1
INNER JOIN reservation AS t2
ON t1.confirmation=t2.confirmation
INNER JOIN products AS t3
ON t1.room=t3.id
WHERE t2.date BETWEEN '$start' AND date'$end'
GROUP BY t2.confirmation") or die(mysql_error());
```

I got result as 
Date

1. 01/08/2014
2. 02/08/2014
3. 03/08/2014
4. 04/08/2014
5. 05/08/2014
6. 14/08/2014
7. 05/09/2014

It includes the date for the month of september. Please help.

Comment: Is this [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]? Surely, it can't be both

Comment: Also, what datatype is `date`?

Comment: That's what you get for storing your dates as strings and in a non-standard format

Comment: Strongly, strongly suggest you go do some reading before proceeding.

Comment: @Mureinik varchar(30) datatype for my date

Comment: Why do you have a group by clause but no aggregate functions in the select list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the str_to_date function like so:

```
SELECT t1.qty,
       t2.lastname,
       t2.firstname,
       t2.date,
       t3.name,
       t2.reservation_id,
       t2.payable
  FROM prodinventory AS t1
 INNER JOIN reservation AS t2
    ON t1.confirmation = t2.confirmation
 INNER JOIN products AS t3
    ON t1.room = t3.id
 WHERE str_to_date(t2.date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN
       str_to_date('$start', '%d/%m/%Y') AND
       str_to_date('$end', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

I also got rid of your GROUP BY clause. You only use the GROUP BY clause in conjunction with aggregate functions. You are not using any aggregate functions.

Of course, the ideal thing to do would be to modify the table to actually hold the date, rather than a string. That way you could query without having to convert. You would also be able to index the date column directly rather than have to create a function based index.

Comment: a SQLFiddle for str_to_date http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76931/9

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth thanks, so to OP - here is an example of the conversion: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76931/11/0

Comment: What datatype of date should be?

Comment: @user3896397 yes it will work in varchar(30). The query I posted does assume all of your date strings are in the format you posted though: 2 digit day / 2 digit month / 4 digit year . Just put the query in my answer inside your quotes

Comment: It works, but it double the output.

Comment: @user3896397 that doesn't have anything to do with the date conversion. There is probably a one to many relationship between 2 of the tables you're joining to. To diagnose how to fix that we would need to know the columns on each table and some sample data. However if the rows are simply complete duplicates across all result columns you can use DISTINCT, ie. "SELECT DISTINCT" and then the rest of the query.

Comment: Finally Solved! Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE t2.date BETWEEN '$start' AND date'$end'
```

this `date'$end'` does not look good. Fix it. And what type is your `t2.date` field?

Update: If you need only month info then you could use your varchar field with LIKE '%/08/2014' condition. The other way is to use STR_TO_DATE(str,fmt) and your condition would be
`STR_TO_DATE(t2.date,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$start','%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$end','%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to fix that. Here's the original WHERE t2.date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' My date field is varchar(30)

Answer (score 2):

If the type of t2.date is datetime, your query is look like this

> WHERE (t2.date BETWEEN '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-01
>   00:00:00')

If the type of t2.date is varchar or text, your query is look like this,

> WHERE t2.date BETWEEN CAST('2014-08-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-09-01'
>   AS DATE);

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be use a LIKE operator.

**LIKE '%/08/2014'**

Ex:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT t1.qty, t2.lastname, t2.firstname, t2.date, t3.name,      t2.reservation_id, t2.payable FROM prodinventory AS t1
INNER JOIN reservation AS t2
ON t1.confirmation=t2.confirmation
INNER JOIN products AS t3
ON t1.room=t3.id
WHERE t2.date LIKE '%/08/2014'
GROUP BY t2.confirmation") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you have not changed MYSql configuration the date format should be YYYY-MM-DD
So it would become

**LIKE '2014-08-%'**

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 1):

this works for me if the "t2.date" field is a TIMESTAMP:

```
"... WHERE DATE(t2.date) BETWEEN '{$start}' AND '{$end}' "
```

Comment: He said it's a varchar

Comment: then he has to use the CAST() function of MySQL

Comment: should I change the datatype into date?

Comment: @StrgAltEntf he would use str_to_date in mysql

Comment: My output in date goes like this '0000-00-00'